# No Sound from speakers in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound

I am new to Ubuntu 20.04. I have a Hp Laptop.I am getting sound in my headset but I can't get sound in the speaker though the settings shows it's getting sound output.but I can't hear anything from speakers but in case of headset it's totally ok.how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would unplug the headphones and do a complete shutdown (not a reboot) Restart and then see if the sound works from the laptop speakers. It worked for me when I had this very similar issue. If not, go into sound settings and see what device is listed as active. Then plug in the headphones. It should change output devices. Removing the headphones should then revert to built in audio or similar.

Comment: I did this.The thing is it's shown sound is output at the sound settings when Headphone is unplugged but I don't hear any sound from the speaker.The speaker is good (and not muted obviously ) as I have dual boot and checked it on windows.